# What other blockchains are similar to EOS that make use of the entire network's "resources"?

Tags: resources

Is there another blockchain like EOS that has to do with resources? I like the fact that you can stake eos to get permission to use parts of the networks "resources". Was wondering what other blockchains have such a concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other blockchains in different stages of starting up which are based on the same code base called, EOSIO.

[Worbli](https://www.worbli.io/), [Telos](https://telosfoundation.io/)

The main feature required for this type of resource allocation is DPOS and there are not many blockchains with that at their base. This doens't work on a POW blockchain.

You can also start a EOSIO private blockchain on some servers and have all the resources for yourself.

And as @confused00 wrote in the comment below, steem and any graphene based blockchain.

Comment: also steem uses a similar model to eosio and maybe other graphene-based chains